# Стили форматирования DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Есть DataGridView, который отображает коллекцию экземпляров SomeClass.

```
public class SomeClass
    {
        public float FloatValue { get; set; }
        public int Format { get; set; }
    }
```

Причем отображать нужно только свойство FloatValue, а после запятой показывать количество знаков, которое лежит в свойстве Format. Источником данных для DataGridView является BindingList. Для отображения FloatValue в конструкторе создана колонка DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, в качестве DataPropertyName указан FloatValue. Свойство Format может быть изменено в процессе исполнения программы.

Варианты, которыми я пытаюсь решить задачу:

1 вариант. Все работает как надо, но очень сильно тормозит, поэтому не могу использовать этот вариант.

```
private void dataGridView_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    SomeClass someClass = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as SomeClass;

    string limitFormat = "F" + someClass.Format.ToString();

    dataGridView.Columns["FloatValue"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = limitFormat;
}
```

2 вариант. При смене свойства Format выставляю флаг NeedFormat. В RowPrePaint при взведенном флаге произвожу форматирование и сбрасываю его. При первом отображении видно, что мелькают нужные значения, но потом нулевые дробные части сокращаются ("400" вместо "400,00").

Можно ли все же как-то разово изменить DefaultCellStyle.Format? Да и почему он вообще возвращается в другой формат?

Answer (score 0):

В итоге использовал другой ивент DGV. Все отображается как надо и не лагает.

```
private void dataGridView_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex < 0 || e.ColumnIndex < 0)
        return;

    SomeClass someClass = dataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as SomeClass;

    string limitFormat = "F" + someClass.Format.ToString();
    float displayValue = float.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
    e.Value = displayValue.ToString(limitFormat);
}
```